# Is there an elegant solution to select elements from a dataframe and create a network graph from it?

Tags: r, dataframe, networking, analysis

My research is in economics and I wonder if I can select a matrix, so a certain amount of rows and a certain amount of columns, from a dataframe and store it directly as a network graph, with nodes and edges.

The dataframes I am working with are public and here available. http://www.wiod.org/database/wiots16. They are quite large. so far i can select for example

```
exampleselection <- wiot [57:113, 62:117]
```

So the 57th to 113th row and 62 to 117 column. Now I want to put these elements into a network theoretical graph. Here the elements selected by the above function should represent the edges and I would like to add nodes in the form of nod1.... to nod56. I already know this tutorial with igraph http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph but it doesnt touch on the topic directly I think.

Aja and the graph should be weighted and directed.

Thanks a lot I appreciate any help. btw I am still quite new to R, actually its my first R project.

Regards

Yannick

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. As a beginner I was just missing the right combination of commands. It is very simple. Use the Matrix package and the igraph package and do it like this:

```
library(Matrix)
matrix.World <- data.matrix(wiot [1:2464, 6:2469])

library(igraph)

g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix.World, mode = c("directed"), 
weighted = TRUE, diag = TRUE, add.colnames = NULL, add.rownames = NULL)
```

hope that helps other people, too!

Yannick